# Is there a way to not have part of canvas reload every time state is changed in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I just added the `react-color` module to this canvas page. When the user picks a color, the `strokeStyle` correctly changes to that color, but it also resets the entire canvas, making it a blank slate. Is there any way to change this so just the color itself changes but the canvas doesn't reset? I tried adding `shouldComponentUpdate` but that only made it so the color didn't change at all.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Layer, Stage, Image } from 'react-konva';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { GithubPicker } from 'react-color';

class Canvas extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.canvasEvent = this.canvasEvent.bind(this);
    this.props.socket.on('canvas_update', data => {
      const idToUpdate = data.canvasId == 1 ? 'drawing2' : 'drawing1';
      const node = document.createElement('p');
      const textNode = document.createTextNode('test');
      node.appendChild(textNode);
      document.getElementById(idToUpdate).appendChild(node);
      console.log(data.canvasJSON);
      this.updateKonva(idToUpdate, data.canvasJSON);

      //this.renderDisabledKonva(undefined, data.canvasJSON, data.canvasId);
    });
    this.state = {
      background: '#fff',
    };
  }

  canvasEvent(canvasJSON) {
    this.props.socket.emit('canvas_event', { roomId: this.props.roomId, canvasJSON: canvasJSON, canvasId: this.props.canvasId }, () => {});
  }

  handleChangeComplete = (color) => {
    this.setState({ background: color.hex });
  };

  renderTools() {
    return (
      <div className="tool">
        Tool:
        <select id="tool">
          <option value="brush">Brush</option>
          <option value="eraser">Eraser</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderKonva(container) {
    const that = this;
    const width = 400; // window.innerWidth;
    const height = 400; // window.innerHeight - 25;
    // first we need Konva core things: stage and layer
    const stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: `drawing${this.props.canvasId}`,
      width: width,
      height: height
    });
    const layer = new Konva.Layer({});
    stage.add(layer);
    // then we are going to draw into special canvas element
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = stage.width() / 1.5;
    canvas.height = stage.height() / 1.5;
    // created canvas we can add to layer as 'Konva.Image' element
    let image = new Konva.Image({
      image: canvas,
      x: stage.width() / 6,
      y: stage.height() / 6,
      stroke: '#05AFF2',
      shadowBlur: 5,
    });
    layer.add(image);
    stage.draw();
    // Now we need to get access to context element
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.strokeStyle = this.state.background;
    context.lineJoin = 'round';
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    let isPaint = false;
    let lastPointerPosition;
    let mode = 'brush';
    // now we need to bind some events
    // we need to start drawing on mousedown
    // and stop drawing on mouseup
    stage.on('contentMousedown.proto', () => {
      isPaint = true;
      lastPointerPosition = stage.getPointerPosition();
    });
    stage.on('contentMouseup.proto', () => {
      isPaint = false;
    });
    // and core function - drawing
    stage.on('contentMousemove.proto', () => {
      if (!isPaint) {
        return;
      }
      if (mode === 'brush') {
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
      }
      if (mode === 'eraser') {
        context.lineWidth = 15;
        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
      }
      context.beginPath();
      let localPos = {
        x: lastPointerPosition.x - image.x(),
        y: lastPointerPosition.y - image.y(),
      };
      context.moveTo(localPos.x, localPos.y);
      const pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
      localPos = {
        x: pos.x - image.x(),
        y: pos.y - image.y(),
      };
      context.lineTo(localPos.x, localPos.y);
      context.closePath();
      context.stroke();
      lastPointerPosition = pos;
      layer.draw();

      const dataURL = stage.toDataURL();
      // window.open(dataURL);
      that.canvasEvent(dataURL);
      // that.canvasEvent(stage.toJSON());
      // console.log(layer);
    });
    const select = document.getElementById('tool');
    select.addEventListener('change', () => {
      mode = select.value;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {this.renderTools()}
        <GithubPicker onChangeComplete={this.handleChangeComplete} color={this.state.background} />
        <div id={'drawing' + this.props.canvasId} ref={ref => this.renderKonva(ref)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.authReducer.isAuthenticated,
  user: state.authReducer,
  roomId: state.roomReducer.currentUserRoom,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({}, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Canvas);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I didn't find a way to only have partial reload, I did put together a workaround for this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Layer, Stage, Image } from 'react-konva';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { GithubPicker } from 'react-color';

class Canvas extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.canvasEvent = this.canvasEvent.bind(this);
    this.props.socket.on('canvas_update', data => {
      const idToUpdate = data.canvasId == 1 ? 'drawing2' : 'drawing1';
      const node = document.createElement('p');
      const textNode = document.createTextNode('test');
      node.appendChild(textNode);
      document.getElementById(idToUpdate).appendChild(node);
      this.updateKonva(idToUpdate, data.canvasJSON);
      this.handleChangeComplete = this.handleChangeComplete.bind(this);
      //this.renderDisabledKonva(undefined, data.canvasJSON, data.canvasId);
    });
  }

  handleChangeComplete(color) {
    newColor = color.hex;
  }

  canvasEvent(canvasJSON) {
    this.props.socket.emit('canvas_event', { roomId: this.props.roomId, canvasJSON: canvasJSON, canvasId: this.props.canvasId }, () => {});
  }

  renderTools() {
    return (
      <div className="tool">
        Tool:
        <select id="tool">
          <option value="brush">Brush</option>
          <option value="eraser">Eraser</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderKonva(container) {
    const that = this;
    const width = 400; // window.innerWidth;
    const height = 400; // window.innerHeight - 25;
    // first we need Konva core things: stage and layer
    const stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: `drawing${this.props.canvasId}`,
      width: width,
      height: height
    });
    const layer = new Konva.Layer({});
    stage.add(layer);
    // then we are going to draw into special canvas element
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = stage.width() / 1.5;
    canvas.height = stage.height() / 1.5;
    // created canvas we can add to layer as 'Konva.Image' element
    let image = new Konva.Image({
      image: canvas,
      x: stage.width() / 6,
      y: stage.height() / 6,
      stroke: '#05AFF2',
      shadowBlur: 5,
    });
    layer.add(image);
    stage.draw();
    // Now we need to get access to context element
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // context.strokeStyle = this.state.background;
    context.lineJoin = 'round';
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    let isPaint = false;
    let lastPointerPosition;
    let mode = 'brush';
    // now we need to bind some events
    // we need to start drawing on mousedown
    // and stop drawing on mouseup
    stage.on('contentMousedown.proto', () => {
      isPaint = true;
      lastPointerPosition = stage.getPointerPosition();
    });
    stage.on('contentMouseup.proto', () => {
      isPaint = false;
    });
    // and core function - drawing
    stage.on('contentMousemove.proto', () => {
      if (!isPaint) {
        return;
      }
      if (mode === 'brush') {
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
      }
      if (mode === 'eraser') {
        context.lineWidth = 15;
        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
      }
      context.beginPath();
      let localPos = {
        x: lastPointerPosition.x - image.x(),
        y: lastPointerPosition.y - image.y(),
      };
      context.moveTo(localPos.x, localPos.y);
      const pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
      localPos = {
        x: pos.x - image.x(),
        y: pos.y - image.y(),
      };
      context.lineTo(localPos.x, localPos.y);
      context.closePath();
      context.stroke();
      lastPointerPosition = pos;
      layer.draw();
      context.strokeStyle = newColor;
      const dataURL = stage.toDataURL();
      // window.open(dataURL);
      that.canvasEvent(dataURL);
      // that.canvasEvent(stage.toJSON());
      // console.log(layer);
    });
    const select = document.getElementById('tool');
    select.addEventListener('change', () => {
      mode = select.value;
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {this.renderTools()}
        <GithubPicker onChangeComplete={this.handleChangeComplete} />
        <div id={'drawing' + this.props.canvasId} ref={ref => this.renderKonva(ref)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

let newColor = '#fff';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.authReducer.isAuthenticated,
  user: state.authReducer,
  roomId: state.roomReducer.currentUserRoom,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({}, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Canvas);
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a couple ways to go about this:

1. If you want to persist any sort of information, just add it to the state. During a re-render, just refer to the state to make sure things still render as they were.
2. Break things up into smaller components and add shouldComponentUpdate to them. Keep breaking things up until you have the granular control you need. Remember, this function also passes the next props and next state as arguments, so you can observe those properties and only render if something relevant to the component has changed, otherwise, return false.

Note: If you're using an external library, react-color, and you're trying to prevent some of it's components from rendering, but don't have access to it, you can just put a wrapper component around it purely to control render conditions.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is a helpful response. I did find a way around this by not using state at all for that library, but next time I might just try breaking things up into smaller components.